# Convert a Ajax Json String to a JS Object for my Ajax Get Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I ideally want the Ajax result to be converted from Jsonstring to OBJ   Thank You in advance.

I know the AJAX  GET script is working becuase when I alert the Ajax Post result I see the Contents in json string format as below.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));

[{"id":"1","username":"jiten","name":"Jitensingh\t","email":"jiten93mail”},{“id":"2","username":"kuldeep","name":"Kuldeep","email":"kuldeemail”}]
```

I want the AJAX  GET result data converted  to look like this in OBJ format like below.

```
{id:31,name:"Mary",username:"R8344",email:"wemail}];
```

PHP/SQL CODE with the Json encoded Array

```
<?php

include "../mytest/config.php";


$return_arr = array();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users  ORDER BY NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Check database connection first
if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
echo 'database connection failed';
die();


} else {


    
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

  $id = $row['id'];
  $username = $row['username'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  
   $return_arr[] = array(

   "id" => $id,
   "username" => $username,
   "name" => $name,
   "email" => $email);
    
}
    
// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
    
    }


?>
```

php echo _encode array above returns below Json string format

```
[{"id":"1","username":"jiten","name":"Jitensingh\t","email":"jiten93mail”},{“id":"2","username":"kuldeep","name":"Kuldeep","email":"kuldeemail”}]
```

I am looking for something like below.( top half of the script)

```
<script>        
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxfile.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result){
       var data =(JSONstring convert to OBJ(result);

       //-----The top half of script -------------  
         
    $.each(data, function( i, person ) {
    if(i == 0) {
      $('.card').find('.person_id').text(person.id);
      $('.card').find('.person_name').text(person.name);
      $('.card').find('.person_username').text(person.username);
      $('.card').find('.person_email').text(person.email);
    } else {
      var personDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone();
      personDetailCloned.find('.person_id').text(person.id);
      personDetailCloned.find('.person_name').text(person.name);
      personDetailCloned.find('.person_username').text(person.username);
      personDetailCloned.find('.person_email').text(person.email);
      
      $('.card-container').append(personDetailCloned); 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I will need help with the closing tags as above is just an example

Comment: Hi , is ajax call successful ? are you seeing any errror inside browser console ?

Comment: Hello Swati,  The Ajax post above is an example, I will test it now, but I have problems with the script closing tags, I  am new to JS.  Some help will be appriciated thanks.

Comment: Hi, please can you elaborate more what do you mean by `I have problems with the script closing tags,..` ? Check your browser console..if there are any error

Comment: use `let data = $.parseJSON(result);` I'm assuming your ajax is successful.

Comment: I will try Malik thank you.

Comment: Swati thanks for introducing me to the browser console

Comment: Malik it did not work, but thanks.   Swati you browser console advice helped me find and solve  the colsing tags issue Thanks!!  :-)     I then was able to  find the solution. which is    " success: function(result){
        data =(result);

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
success: function(result){
data =(result);
```

There was no need o convert the data to OBJ or anything ( blush). Then the code on the 2nd half of the Ajax script will receive the data and populate.  Thanks to all contributors.